# Issue in finding the lat and long in samsung S3

Tags: android, location

I am not getting the lat and long in samsung S3.In other devices my code is working fine and getting the proper lat and long.Below is my code to get the lat and long.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView1;
Location currentLocation;
double currentLatitude,currentLongitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    findLocation();


}

 public void findLocation() {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                updateLocation(location,currentLatitude,currentLongitude);

                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        String.valueOf(currentLatitude) + "\n"
                                + String.valueOf(currentLongitude), 5000)
                        .show();

                }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }


    void updateLocation(Location location,double currentLatitude,double currentLongitude) {
            currentLocation = location;
            this.currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            this.currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();


            textView1.setText(String.valueOf(this.currentLatitude) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(this.currentLongitude));

        }
}
```

In above code the onLocationChanged() method is not executing in S3 and the same code is not working in Samsung S3 device.In other devices it working fine.I am getting the correct lat and long in other devices.Please help me to sort out this problem..

Comment: This maybe non-sense but I face this couple of times and still no explanations, in some SamSung devices, seems like the GPS function having trouble, I got same problem in SamSung Note II and SamSung S3 Mini. Other devices works perfectly.

Comment: But sometime it works fine in S3.But now not working.. Can u please explain why?

Comment: Sorry but I still get the explanation, Im trying to figure it out, I guess it is because of the hardware or could possibly be the Android SDK fail from the Manufacturer, in this case is SamSung